# jQuery mousewheel animate

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to do some smooth scrolling/easing on a divs top position based on a draggable divs top position.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="drag">MOVE ME</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#drag').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    drag: function() {
        $('#content').animate({'top': $(this).css('top')}, 200);   
    }
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TDe74/)

The position of the content div are also being changed by mousewheel so the solution can not be specific to jQuery UI.

How would I do easing on the position of the content div?

Comment: The provided link appears to be broken :/

Comment: please post relevant code in addition to links (working links)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Do you want to scroll the second first div same as second

Answer (score 0):

Assuming .draggable is the trigger for a drag event, this is how you'd scroll the page so that the #drag div is at the top after moving it.

```
$('#drag').draggable(function(){
    var offset  = ($(this).offset().top) - scrollTop;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:offset}, 'slow');
});
```

now if you want a div to move to #drag's top just use a different selector and .css()